# Not able to store Product and It's Attachment using visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, class, attachment, product

Here, i am going to build a visualforce page to add Product and attach photo of that product in attachment but i am not sure why it's not working..

Please have a look into my code and suggest !!

Visualforce Page :

```
<apex:page standardController="Product2" extensions="productManagementController" tabStyle="product2" sidebar="false">
<script>
  var blobfile;
  function getAsText(readFile) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(readFile);
    reader.onload = attLoaded;
  }
  function attLoaded(evt) {  
    var fileString = evt.target.result;
    blobfile = fileString;
    var  input = document.getElementById("fileId");
    var filename= input.value;          
    passToController(filename,blobfile);
  }
  function remoteLocationPost(){
    var fbody= document.getElementById("fileId").files[0];
    getAsText(fbody); 
  }   
</script>

<apex:form id="frm">
<apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:pageBlockSection title="Add Product">
                <apex:inputfield value="{!prd.Name}"/>
        <apex:inputfield value="{!prd.ProductCode}"/>
        <apex:inputfield value="{!prd.Group__c}"/>
            <apex:outputLabel value="Upload Image" />
                <input type="file" id="fileId" name="attFile" />
                <apex:actionFunction name="passToController" action="{!savePrd}" reRender="frm">
                    <apex:param name="fname" value="" assignTo="{!filename}" />
                    <apex:param name="body" value="" assignTo="{!body}"/>
                </apex:actionFunction><br/>
                <apex:commandButton style="margin-left:50%;" Value="Add Product" onclick="remoteLocationPost();"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

Apex Class :

```
public class productManagementController{

public product2 prd{get;set;}
public String filename{get;set;}
public String body{get;set;}
public Attachment attachment{get;set;}

public productManagementController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

prd = new product2();
    attachment = new Attachment();

}

public void savePrd(){

    insert prd;
    attachment.Name = filename;
    attachment.Body = Blob.valueOf(body);
    attachment.Parentid = prd.Id; //Needs to add your record id below which you need attachment ;
    insert attachment;
    update prd;

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can pass body using `apex:actionFunction` because it always accept string as parameter.

So use `apex:inputfile` to pass the file to controller. It will solve your problem.

Comment: i used this tag "apex:inputfile" but it's giving me an error "apex:inputFile can not be used in conjunction with an action component, apex:commandButton or apex:commandLink that specifies a rerender or oncomplete attribute."

Comment: @Nihar Yes you need to remove `rerender` attribute from your `commandButton and actionfunction`.